# Windows 7 shows blank (black) screen after welcome screen with just mouse pointer

Tags: windows-7, black-screen-of-death

I have got Samsung laptop with Windows 7 Ultimate on it. It just suddenly failed to start. It boots to Welcome screen then it just goes blank with mouse pointer. But I was able to boot into safe mode without any issues. I tried following solutions in safe mode:

```
1. Checked with antivirus and antimalware -- found nothing
2. Boot in low resolution mode -- not working, get stuck after welcome screen
3. Disabled "Windows Event Log" as suggested at some forum -- it booted in normal mode once but then when I performed restart, same issue - gets stuck.
```

Now, when it boots in safe mode, it gets stuck (hard disk led keeps on - doesn't flicker at all) just after it shows desktop and after around 5 minutes I am able to perform something.

Is some hardware failing eg. HDD, RAM etc. or there is something else I can try?

Thanks.

Comment: Did you try Safe Mode?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

possible bad sectors.

from a command prompt

chkdsk /r c:

if it says do this after reboot??
Say Yes
then reboot and wait for it to complete.

Comment: Thanks. It worked. It was bad cluster related to Windows Event Log.